# invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*

Tags: c++

I don't have much experience in C++. I have a function `std::string Exec(char* cmd)`. It runs for `cout<<Exec("hello!")`, but it doesn't run for std::string: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*. I was wondering how I can fix it.

```
std::string s="hello";
char * c = s.c_str();
Exec(c);
```

Comment: Make it `std::string Exec(const char* cmd)`.

Comment: Well, because your function might mutate the `char*` , but it can't because it's a const. Like juanchopanza said, change the function signature.

Comment: Make it `const char * c = s.c_str();`. Not rocket surgery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that's because [`c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) returns a `const char *` and not a `char *`

Just change the line to:

```
const char * c = s.c_str();
```

and the function declaration to

```
std::string Exec(const char* cmd)
```

Like noted before and you're good to go.
[See it live here.](http://ideone.com/mZhyNj)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your prototype to this:

```
std::string Exec(const char* cmd)
```

since you want to pass a `const char*` as an argument.

Otherwise, you can pass a `char*` as an argument.

That's why your's `cout<<Exec("hello!")` works, because the argument is passed as non-const!

Answer (score 0):

The correct signature for what you're attempting to do would be

```
std::string Exec(const char* cmd)
```

because in either cases you're passing a string constant to it. Even if the `Exec("hello")` case compiles, that doesn't mean it's safe to use:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::string Exec(char* cmd) {
    cout << cmd;
    cmd[0] = 'S'; // Undefined behavior
    cout << cmd;
    return std::string("");
}

int main() {
    Exec("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ZY6Atr